# Highlighting text while typing in a text box in asp.net

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, text, textbox

Can anyone help me out with this problem. I want to highlight the text while typing in a TextBox. How can I do this?

Comment: You want to highlight text in that TextBox or some place else ? Please be more specific.

Answer (score 1):

You can use css

```
input:hover {color:green}
input:active {color:blue}
input {color:red}
```

or javascript...

```
<input  ...
onfocus="this.style.backgroundColor='#FEFDE0';"
onblur="this.style.backgroundColor='#FFFFFF';"
>
```

Comment: it is coloring the whole background of the TextBox. I need only the text to be highlighted like when we press the mouse and run over the text to select it